# hyperref and number of section?

Tags: hyperref

I am using hyperref to cite my section

```
\section{Classical Imaging}
\label{Classical Imaging}
```

and to cite it I use

```
\nameref{Classical Imaging}
```

But I obtain:

[image]

Do you know how to sobstitute the name with 2.2 in that case?

Comment: `\ref{Classical Imaging}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\section{Introduction}
In the section \ref{sec: Classical Imaging}


\section{Proof Environment}


\subsection{reandom}
\subsection{Classical Imaging}
\label{sec: Classical Imaging}
```

Write the \ref{} command to obtain the reference number.

Also, visit my youtube channel [WPG](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy0vz71kvXSJSmrzHGL77Rg) for LaTex Tutorials.